# How can we derive Laplace's equation from a physical system?

Tags: mathematics, differential-equations

Question is basically what I've stated above. I'm trying to look for systems we can derive Laplace's equation from (since apparently there are a lot of really cool different ones?), and I'm starting to realize I really don't know how despite having scoured the internet for at least 4 hours for this. Would really appreciate it if anyone could help me figure out where to look or how to approach the derivation (for literally any system it works for tbh).

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

At the surface of the Earth, the acceleration of gravity is:
$$\mathbf g = -\frac{GM\mathbf {\hat r}}{r^2}$$ The vector $\mathbf g$ can be made a gradient of a scalar field:
$\mathbf g = -\nabla \phi$, where $$\phi = -\frac{GM}{r}$$

where $r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}$

Indeed, making the gradient:
$$\nabla \phi = \left(\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y},\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial z}\right) = \frac{GM}{(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}(x,y,z) = \frac{GM}{r^3}\mathbf r = \frac{GM\mathbf {\hat r}}{r^2}$$

Making the divergence of the gradient we get the Laplacian:
$$\nabla^2 \phi = \nabla \mathbf . (\nabla \phi) = \frac{\partial^2  \phi}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial y^2} + \frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial z^2}$$

If you make all the derivatives, the result will be: $\nabla^2 \phi = 0$

Comment: It was wrong. I edited. Thanks.

Comment: Oh whoa, this is really interesting. And honestly surprisingly simple tbh. So you can do this for other systems as well, right? Like electric potential, or others too?

Comment: Hi, looking at this again. What do you mean by "if you make all of the derivatives," in the absolute last line?

Comment: @Applesauce44 making the second derivatives from the first derivatives, that are the components of the gradient vector.

Comment: Ohhh okay okay, so you're just summarizing the equation that you wrote above that, right?

Comment: yes, if you use the already calculated first derivatives, make the second derivatives, and sum them, the result must be zero.

Comment: Ahhh yes okay, that makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Laplace's equation $\nabla^2\phi=0$ has $\phi=\varphi_1-\varphi2$ as a solution provided the $\varphi_i$ solve Poisson's equation $\nabla^2\varphi=f$, and $\varphi$ as a solution for any Poisson-solving $\varphi$ with $f=0$. So it behooves us to consider why *Poisson's* equation arises in physics. You're probably familiar with the cases where $\varphi$ is a [gravitational](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson%27s_equation#Newtonian_gravity) or [electrostatic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson%27s_equation#Electrostatics)
potential, but I'll keep the discussion more general.

Poisson's equation is the field-theoretic equivalent of Newton's second law $\ddot{x}=F/m$ for constant mass $m$, with the replacements $x\mapsto\varphi,\,\frac{d}{dt}\mapsto\nabla,\,\frac{F}{m}\mapsto f$. (You could argue Laplace's equation is really the equivalent of Newton's *first* law.) Just as Newton follows from the Lagrangian $\frac12m\dot{x}^2-V$ with $F=-\nabla V$, Poisson's equation follows from the Lagrangian density $\frac12(\nabla\varphi)^2-V(\varphi)$ for $V^\prime=-f$. (In the case of Laplace's equation, $f=0$ so we may as well take $V=0$.) This is a static Lagrangian density in which the quadratic term is a kinetic energy cost, so Poisson's equation emerges from the minimization of a field-dependent energy in some volume. (If you work with a Hamiltonian, you can instead describe it in terms of energy conservation.)

Comment: Oh whoa... so I've never thought of this in terms of Newton's laws so that's pretty cool. Thanks for this answer!